# How do I get the navbar to stop disappearing when a user clicks a nav link?

Tags: javascript, user-interface, scroll

Anything that scrolls down makes the nav bar disappear, and I don't want that. I only want it to disappear on scroll. I've tried removing the scroll function on the window object on scroll, all sorts of stuff. Have been stuck on this for a couple of days. I understand why it does it, because I have the functionality built in for the nav to disappear when scrolled downwards. On click only, though, I don't want this to happen - I want the nav to stay.

Any help would be appreciated. Been stuck on this for a few days now. Not sure how to remove the scroll event from the window to get it to work.

```js
'use strict';
var section = document.querySelectorAll(".section");
var sections = {};
var i = 0;

const arr = Array.from(section)
arr.forEach(function(el) {
  sections[el.id] = el.offsetTop;
});

window.onscroll = function() {
  var scrollPosition = document.documentElement.scrollTop || document.body.scrollTop;

  for (i in sections) {
    if (sections[i] <= scrollPosition) {
      document.querySelector('.active').setAttribute('class', ' ');
      document.querySelector('a[href*=' + i + ']').setAttribute('class', 'active');
    }
  }
};


var nav = document.querySelector('.nav');
var navText = document.querySelectorAll(".links");

function scrolling() {
  // Initial state
  var scrollPos = 0;
  // adding scroll event
  addEventListener('scroll', function(e) {
    // detects new state and compares it with the old one
    if ((document.body.getBoundingClientRect()).top > scrollPos)
      nav.style.visibility = "visible"
    if ((document.body.getBoundingClientRect()).top < scrollPos)
      nav.style.visibility = "hidden"
    // saves the new position for iteration.
    scrollPos = (document.body.getBoundingClientRect()).top;
  });
}

scrolling();
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  font: 24px 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  background: url("images/someTree.jpg") no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

header {
  opacity: 0.9;
  width: 100%;
  height: 85px;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1000;
  background-color: #96C339;
}

header h1#logo {
  float: left;
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  font-size: 40px;
  color: #FFF;
  font-weight: 400;
  margin-left: 35px;
}

header nav {
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
}

header nav a {
  line-height: 100px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  color: #FFF;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a {
  font-family: 'Droid Sans', serif;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 40px;
}

.active {
  font-family: 'Droid Sans', serif;
  font-size: 22px;
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 40px;
}

#about {
  background-color: #fff;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  opacity: 0.6;
}

#skills {
  background-color: #fff;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  opacity: 0.6;
}

#contact {
  background-color: #fff;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  opacity: 0.6;
}

@media all and (max-width: 770px) {
  header h1#logo {
    font-size: 30px;
    display: block;
    float: none;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 100px;
    line-height: 55px;
    text-align: center;
  }
  header nav {
    display: block;
    float: none;
    height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: -65px;
  }
  header nav a {
    font-size: 15px;
    line-height: 50px;
    margin: 0 5px;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="portfolio.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto">
<div class="wrapper">
  <header class="nav">
    <h1 id="logo">DMac</h1>
    <nav>
      <a href="#about" class="active">About</a>
      <a href="#skills">Skills</a>
      <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <div id="about" class="section"></div>
  <div id="skills" class="section"></div>
  <div id="contact" class="section"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I achieved this by using Bootstrap on one of my earlier projects. If you want to use bootstrap, you can use 'fixed-top class' to fix it when you click or scroll. More info you can find here;

[https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/position/#fixed-top][1]